# Cycle2 Pager Is Not Showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, cycle2

i m using jquery cycle2 slider but my jquery cycle2 slider pager is not showing on slider images even i tried there demo code i want to display pager at the bottom of the slider but its not align please check my code and help me out.

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 777;
}

/* Top Menu Start Here */

.top_nav{
    height: 90px;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    transition:all 0.7s ease;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.7s ease;
    -moz-transition:all 0.7s ease;
    -o-transition:all 0.7s ease;
    -ms-transition:all 0.7s ease;
}

.container{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ24kd_2tEzjbb_GdPnMQKog7lMCxtYmmy7dxjjpDr6d2ZseK-Dig");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    top: 0;
}

.site-dt{
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 573px;
    width: 100%;
}


#slider-main{
    height: 578px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

#slider-main #slider img{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.section_about{
    height: 573px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #de5670;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
<Script type ="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.io/min/jquery.cycle2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<header>
    <div class="top_nav">
    </div>
</header>
<div class="container">
</div>
<div id="slider-main">
<div id="slider" class="cycle-slideshow" 
    data-cycle-fx=scrollHorz
    data-cycle-timeout=2000
    >
    <div class="cycle-pager">

    </div>
<img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p1.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p2.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p3.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p4.jpg">
</div>
</div>
<div class="section_about">

</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tweaked this a bit in a fiddle. The html was a bit confused and I think you may have added too much overlapping css. Hopefully this will get you in the right direction.

Also you had Jquery loaded twice which never helps :)

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 777;
}

/* Top Menu Start Here */

.top_nav{
    height: 90px;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    transition:all 0.7s ease;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.7s ease;
    -moz-transition:all 0.7s ease;
    -o-transition:all 0.7s ease;
    -ms-transition:all 0.7s ease;
}

.container{
    /*height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;*/
    background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ24kd_2tEzjbb_GdPnMQKog7lMCxtYmmy7dxjjpDr6d2ZseK-Dig");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    top: 0;
}
/*
.site-dt{
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 573px;
    width: 100%;
}


#slider-main{
    height: 578px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

#slider-main #slider img{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
*/
.section_about{
    height: 573px;
    /*width: 100%;*/
    background-color: #de5670;
    /*overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;*/
}

.cycle-pager {
    background: white;
}
.cycle-pager span {
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://malsup.github.io/min/jquery.cycle2.min.js"></script>
<header>
    <div class="top_nav">
    </div>
</header>
<div class="container">

  <div id="slider-main">
    <div id="slider" class="cycle-slideshow" 
      data-cycle-fx=scrollHorz
      data-cycle-timeout=2000
      >
      <div class="cycle-pager">

      </div>
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p1.jpg">
        <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p2.jpg">
        <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p3.jpg">
        <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p4.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="section_about">

  </div>

</div>
```